# What's the term for a value that is not a function?

Tags: computer-science, lazy-evaluation, terminology, theory

Or does the term "value" already exclude functions?

I'm trying to explain why (in JavaScript, for instance) calling `foo(2 + 2)` is different from calling `foo(() => 2 + 2)`, (assuming `foo` can handle a function as argument for the purpose of lazily computing a value). In the first example, the argument that `foo` receives is `4`, while in the second, the argument it receives is the function `() => 2 + 2` itself. I want to describe the difference as "passing a value" versus "passing a function", but I'm wondering if there's a more precise term.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you might be looking for. But functions that receive functions as arguments are called `higher order functions`

Comment: This is not an answer but more like a pointer on a compass. Take a look at Lambda Calculus definitions for [Beta Reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Beta_reduction) and [Eta Conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion). In other words don't think of a value, think of a kind of process needed to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's precedent for this, recently I've started to use the term `nonfunction` in JavaScript to refer to all values that are not functions